# How to pass java variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am trying to create a min date and max date validation form in HTML and javascript. I have some issue about how to solve this problem.

my java code

```
 String sql = "select * from date";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test","root","");
    PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet Re = pre.executeQuery();
    if(Re.next())
    {

        String msdfdate = Re.getString("sdate");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msdfdate);
}
}catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

my javascript code

```
var kkr = <%=msdfdate%>;
       alert(kkr);
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
startdate = dates;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", startdate)
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);
```

How to solve this pass java DB variable to the javascript.

Comment: Try `var kkr = "<%=msdfdate%>";`

Comment: Why you have `JOptionPane` there? `JOptionPane` is Java GUI, i.e. for Java desktop applications. It has nothing to do with JSP (nor servlets), so why it is there?

Comment: Check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727137/passing-variable-from-jsp-to-javascript) out .

Comment: This is showing the following error "The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments".

Comment: refer this link foe solution:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29197836/10971384